# Find the key to which a value belongs in a Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I am a beginner in Python and I have what seems like a simple issue with my code but I can't figure it out.
I have a dictionary with several keys, each of which contains a list of values, and I want to do the following: **For each key, find if its name appears as a value in any other key, and if so, append its contents to that key as well.**

I think it's easier to explain with an example. I have the following:

```
#define the dictionary
Dictionary = {
    "a": ["x", "z"],
    "b": ["y", "w"],
    "c": ["a", "q"],
    "d": ["w", "a"]
    }

#get all the keys from the dictionary
listOfKeys = []
for key in Dictionary.keys():
    listOfKeys.append(key)

#try to append the key values to any matches 
for key, value in Dictionary.items():
    for element in listOfKeys:
        if element in value:
            Dictionary[?].append(Dictionary[element])
```

Obviously, in the last line, instead of "?", I should have the key to which `value` belongs to, but I am not sure how to get it. After doing that, I expect the dictionary to look like this:

```
    "a": ["x", "z"],
    "b": ["y", "w"],
    "c": ["a", "q", "x", "z"],
    "d": ["w", "a", "x", "z"]
```

In other words, the contents of key `a` are added to keys `c` and `d`, because those are the keys in which `a` appears as a value. Ideally I would only append the values if they are not already in that key as well, but I think I can sort that part out myself. I found one solution online (not sure if I can link it here) but it seems to only work if the values are a string, and not a list as in my case.

Hopefully I have explained this clearly enough to be understandable.

Comment: FYI you can just write `listOfKeys = list(Dictionary.keys())`

Comment: You don't even need `listOfKeys`, you can simply use `Dictionary` again: `for element in Dictionary:`.

Comment: Sidenote, capitalized names should be reserved for classes. For an example dict like this, `d` would be a good name instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#define the dictionary
Dictionary = {
    "a": ["x", "z"],
    "b": ["y", "w"],
    "c": ["a", "q"],
    "d": ["w", "a"]
    }

#get all the keys from the dictionary
listOfKeys = list(Dictionary.keys())

for key, value in Dictionary.items():
    items_to_add = []
    for letter in value:
        if letter in listOfKeys:
            items_to_add.append(letter) # Store off the keys whose value we need to append
    for item in items_to_add:           # Run this in a second loop so that we're not modifying a list we're currently iterating through
        for new_item in Dictionary[item]:
            if new_item not in value:   # Only add each item if it's not already in the target list
                value.append(new_item)

# Test that we've done it right
expected = {
    "a": ["x", "z"],
    "b": ["y", "w"],
    "c": ["a", "q", "x", "z"],
    "d": ["w", "a", "x", "z"]}

# Does not throw an Exception because at this point, Dictionary and expected are identical
assert Dictionary == expected
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour]. It would help a lot to add a written description to explain how this code answers the question. See [answer] if you want more tips.

Comment: The second inner loop is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the responses @Chance @Barmar @wjandrea, that works perfectly. One thing I forgot to mention is that I also don't want to add any values from `a` that are already in the target key. So if "d" : ["w", "a", "x"] I want it to end up as d : ["w", "a", "x" "z"] again instead of having `x` two times. My bad that I forgot to mention it but I thought it better to ask here again instead of opening a new question.

Comment: Updated to include the new requirement

Comment: @crimsontides097 That is actually a different question, but it's already been asked: [Add only unique values to a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42334197/4518341)

Answer (score 0):

use `extend()` to append a list to another list. And use `Dictionary[element]` to get the contents of the matching key.

```
if element in value:
    value.extend(Dictionary[element])
```

Answer (score 0):

*"the key to which `value` belongs"* is literally just `key`, but going a step further, `Dictionary[key]` is `value`. So:

```
value.append(Dictionary[element])
```

Although, you'll also want to replace `.append()` with `.extend()` in order to get your desired output.